# gdb debugging non-native (Java) Android apps?

Tags: android, gdb

I started learning the Android-NDK, and learning little about the [suggested](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html), Eclipse-Java-development approach.

To debug non-native apps, it appears there are [more tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html) to learn. It would appear that these tools exist because of something gdb is missing.

Can gdb be used to debug any binary? What would prevent gdb from attaching to a running non-native PID?
Is there any reason why a non-native (Java) app cannot be debugged by gdb?

Answer (score 0):

A similar tool as gdb is jdb, that is working with android. You can find more info in this good blog article: (jswat seems also popular)

http://codeseekah.com/2012/02/16/command-line-android-development-debugging/